# Wicket AjaxButton does not update FeedbackPanel

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to send a success message to a FeedbackPanel in Wicket, if an AjaxButton was clicked. Yet I recieve the following error message:

> Wicket.Ajax.Call.processComponent: Component with id [[065DFC0DD1DC51103CC5FFEE61F2AE12]] was not found while trying to perform markup update.

I am already aware, that I have to output the markupID in the Java Code before I use the AjaxButton and set the target in the `onSubmit`. I also set `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag` once, yet it changed nothing.
I have also created a small test page, where I succeeded in sending the success message to the FeedbackPanel.

I thus started to debug the project and found out that the markupID returned from `DefaultMarkupIdGenerator.generateMarkupId` was indeed different that the one displayed in the HTML. Additionally all FeedbackPanels recieve this markupID during the ajax call.

> feedbackPanelWartung12 vs. 065DFC0DD1DC51103CC5FFEE61F2AE12

To further complicate things, my FeedbackPanel is within a RepeatingView contained in a Panel within a page already containing a FeedbackPanel (inherited from its superclasses). The structure goes as follows:

### Java Code

MyPage

```
public MyPage extends MySuperPage{

    //Constructors were left out

    //this method is called in the onInitialize of some
    //super class.
    @Override
    protected Component newContent() {
        setFeedbackPanelFilter();
        return new MyContainerPanel();
    }

    //this FeedbackPanel shall not recieve messages from child containers
    private void setFeedbackPanelFilter() {
        ((FeedbackPanel) this.get("feedback"))
            .setFilter( new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this) {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(FeedbackMessage message) {
                    return !super.accept(message);
                }
        });
    }
}
```

MyContainerPanel

```
public MyContainerPanel extends Panel {

    //Constructors were left out

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();
        RepeatingView repeater = new RepeatingView("repeater");
        add(repeater);
        for (Object o : objects) {
            String id = repeater.newChildId();
            repeater.add(new MyPanel(id,o));
        }
    }
}
```

MyPanel

```
public MyPanel extends Panel {    
    private Object o;
    private CheckBox chkBox;
    private DateTimeField startDate, endDate;
    private TextField<String> message;
    private Form<Object> form;
    private AjaxButton button;
    private Label name;
    private FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel;

    //Constructors were left out

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
        super.onInitialize();

        initFields();
        addFields();
        addAjaxButton();
        addAjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior();

        if (!o.isMaintenance())
            disableFields();
        }

    private void addAjaxButton() {
        button = new AjaxButton("submit") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Form<?> form) {
                //do something
                feedbackPanel.success("Speichern erfolgreich");
                target.addChildren(AppWartungPanel.this.getPage(), FeedbackPanel.class);
            }
        };
        form.add(button);
    }

    private void addAjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior() {
        chkBox.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                switchVisibility();
                target.add(startDate);
                target.add(endDate);
                target.add(message);
                target.add(feedbackPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private void switchVisibility() {
        if (o.isMaintenance())
            enableFields();
        else
            disableFields();
        }

    private void addFields() {
        add(form);
        form.add(feedbackPanel);
        form.add(chkBox);
        form.add(startDate);
        form.add(endDate);
        form.add(message);
        form.add(name);
    }

    private void initFields() {
        form = new Form<WartungDAO>("form", AppWartungPanel.this.getModel());
        chkBox = new CheckBox("wartung", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(o, "wartung"));
        chkBox.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        startDate = new DateTimeField("startDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(o, "startDate"));
        startDate.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        startDate.setRequired(true);
        endDate = new DateTimeField("endDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(o, "endDate"));
        endDate.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        endDate.setRequired(true);
        message = new TextField<String>("message", new PropertyModel<String>(o, "message"));
        message.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        message.setRequired(true);
        name = new Label("name", new PropertyModel<String>(o, "portal"));
        feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackPanelWartung");
        feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        feedbackPanel.setFilter(new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this));
    }

    private void disableFields() {
        startDate.setEnabled(false);
        endDate.setEnabled(false);
        message.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void enableFields() {
        startDate.setEnabled(true);
        endDate.setEnabled(true);
        message.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

### HTML markup

MyPage

```
<!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <body class="BG_MAIN">
           <div class="grid_16 BG1_GLOBAL">
               <div style="margin:10px;">
                   <div class="grid_3 alpha">
                    <wicket:container wicket:id="menu"></wicket:container>
                </div>
            <div class="grid_12 omega">
        <div class="INHALT">
                <h1 wicket:id="appHeader" style="margin-top: 0;"></h1>
                <div wicket:id="wartung" />
                <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
                <wicket:container wicket:id="content"></wicket:container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

MyContainerPanel

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <wicket:panel>
        <div wicket:id="repeater">
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</html>
```

MyPanel

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <wicket:panel>
        <div style="margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 25px;">
            <form wicket:id="form">
                <h2 wicket:id="name"></h2>
                <div wicket:id="feedbackPanelWartung"></div>
                <table style="border: none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none;">Wartung aktiv?</td>
                            <td style="border: none;">
                                <input wicket:id="wartung" type="checkbox" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none;">Nachricht zum Anzeigen:</td>
                            <td style="border: none;">
                                <input wicket:id="message" type="text" size="50" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none;">Startdatum</td>
                            <td style="border: none;">
                                <div wicket:id="startDate"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none;">Enddatum</td>
                            <td style="border: none;">
                                <div wicket:id="endDate"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                            <td style="border: none;">
                                <input wicket:id="submit" type="submit" value="Speichern" style="float: right;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody> 
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</html>
```

I can only guess that the error is due to the complexity of the page.

I also disabled the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` to check if it messes with the AjaxButton - It did not.
I also implemented everything with a normal Button, to check if the ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter and the FeedbackPanels worked - they did.

The AjaxButton is not crucial to the Page. Yet I would really like to understand, so if anybody has another nice idea to try out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackPanelWartung") {
    @Override
    public String getMarkupId() {
        return "feedbackPanelWartung." + someUniqueValuePassedToThePanel;
    }
};
feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

As luck had it, I had a unique value in one modelObject of the panel. I then overwrote the Component.getMarkupId() method and simply set my Id.
Worked like a charm.

I also found out, that the method `feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);` Was irrelevant to my error message.
In other words: even if I tried to set the markup id for my component, it was never set in the first place and thus the ajax component was, rightfully so, never able to find a target.